# How is state immutability actually used in Redux?

Tags: immutability, redux

I am trying to understand how immutability is actually (if at all) used in Redux. Every tutorial/article/document I found states that reducers should never alter the state object but instead create a new copy of the changed data (i.e. the reducers must be pure functions). I understand this but I could not find any place where there is an explanation of how this guideline is *actually* used by Redux internal implementation.

**Is this just a strong recomendation or will something inside Redux breaks if I make the reducers non pure?**

**If it is the later then what exactly will break?**

I did find several places where Dan says that in some (very rare) cases the reducers may be non pure but it is risky (again, with no explanation what is the risk exactly).

Answer (score 4):

Redux, when used with React, is typically connected by using `connect` from `react-redux`. Wrapping a component with `connect`, makes it subscribe to changes to the redux store by specifying a change handler, which gets invoked after an action is dispatched and the reducers are called. Upon invocation of the change handler, `connect` compares the current state of the store with the new state using identity comparison (`previousState !== newState`) – which is faster than doing a shallow or deep comparison – and only when the two states aren't identical, does it update the wrapped component using `setState`. Mutating the state directly will not cause the references to change, thereby causing the wrapped component to not re-render.

This is how `connect` determines if it should call setState:

```
if (!pure || prevStoreState !== storeState) {
  this.hasStoreStateChanged = true
  this.setState({ storeState })
}
```

`connect` also provides an option to override this behaviour by specifying that the wrapped component is not pure using:

`connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps, {pure: false} )`

Identity comparison is also used by pure components by implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent unnecessary calls to `render`.

TL;DR: a component wrapped with `connect` will not re-render if a store's state changes due to mutation.

Edit: Nothing in Redux itself will break since it is so minimal that it doesn't try to inspect the state returned by reducers.

Comment: TL;DR: immutable data structure make it very easy to detect if something has changed which is a big boost for rendering performance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my question was about Redux itself and not components that use it (I will edit the question to make this clearer). Do you know if something in Redux breaks if the reducers are not pure?

Comment: The other factor to consider is time-travel debugging.  If a reducer is pure, it doesn't matter _what_ state and action it's called with, it will always have the same output.  That means the Redux DevTools can run back and forth with different actions, and the end result will be "correct".  If a reducer mutates state, the time travel ability will break.